# Running a task that is not MapReduced based between stage 1 and 2

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In my mapReduce code I need a task that is not parallel is run after running reducers in stage 1. This task needs output of reducers in stage 1. Then I want to use output of this task in mappers and reducers in stage 2. Since this task is not a parallel task, I do not need write a MapReduce code for it.  Which part of my code should I write its code?

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand well, you have two separete mapreduce jobs? One for stage1 and second for stage2? Quite easy solution for this case could be using Oozie workflow. I am using similar workflow to query external apis (without prallel run):

```
<workflow-app name="TEST" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
    <start to="Test"/>
    <action name="Test">
        <java>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <main-class>com.test.Test</main-class>
            <java-opts>-Xms128M -Xmx2048M</java-opts>
            <arg>-d</arg>
            <arg>${Date_Valid}</arg>
            <file>/lib/api2.jar</file>
        </java>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Just put stage1 job before this java job and stage2 after that.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  where should I put  code of task that is not parallel? it should be run between stage1 and stage2